# Icon in Quasar Button Component does not change size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, icons, quasar-framework

The size Quasar Button component can be adjusted and from [docs](http://quasar-framework.org/components/button.html#Vue-Properties) it seems the icon in a button should change size accordingly. See this picture for example from the docs:
[image]

When I try the icon stays same size (button changes). My code:

```
    <q-btn
      v-if="$route.name === 'resetpassword'"
      class="absolute-top-right"
      flat
      round
      wait-for-ripple
      dense
      size="15px"
      color="primary"
      icon="mdi-window-close"
      @click.native="goToSignIn"
    />
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. The Problem

I ran into the same problem today. But if you change the button size to an extreme number (e.g. 200px), you'll see that the icon **DID** change size with the button.

The problem is that the default padding area between the icon and the button is too big, which **makes the icon look small comparing to the button** itself.

## 2. The Solution

Here's how I solve it using [Deep Selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html). You make a custom button component around your button code. Then give it following style:

```
<style scoped>
.q-btn>>>.q-icon {
  font-size: 40px;
}
</style>
```

And also give the size attribute in your template the same size, so `size="40px"`. Then all aspects of the button have same size.

When using Vue with 3rd party UI Frameworks/Components, `Deep Selector` makes it really easy to make quick changes to component styles. And the changes can also be scoped (only change style locally) if you put the `scoped` keyword.

Comment: I read up on the deep selectors link you gave: good stuff. I think I did try gigantic buttons and still got small icons though... I will test in a couple of days and come back on this!

Comment: Couldn't wait so just tested. I had to make a single file component of the closebutton so I could single out the <style> and make it scoped. Then I can indeed set the size of the icon, BUT it seems now completely isolated from other button css... So the ripple (when hovering or clicking) stays small e.g.; I thought it would be easy-pie, gloops. Any idea how to get 'a consistent size button'.

Comment: If you want a reusable 'consistent size button', you can create your own Component that wraps the <q-btn> with your desired style, and use your own Component instead. You can also style <q-btn> specifically in its parent Page/Component. Its perfectly normal, depends on what you need.

Comment: Deep Selectors should not affect other button CSS, the ripple works like a charm in my button. Are you using the latest Quasar Version?

Comment: "Deep Selectors should not affect other button CSS". Well that is the behavior I have, i.e. the icon is large, but the ripple is small (and still works). But I need the ripple to grow with the icon-size, right?! BTW the window in which the icon is gets an window overflow, probably because my button is in the corner and the padding or the container of the button stays small too, thus the icon grows out of the window..., so also padding or other css 'is not affected'... Hope I'm clear... My quasar version is 0.15.10 (quasar-cli 015.14).

Comment: Ah, looks good now! You need to also set the size attribute in the component to the same pixel size and then 'everything is same size'. Will edit your answer accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to use `q-icon` inside `q-btn` for changing the size of the icon.

```
<q-btn size="xs" color="primary" dense>
    <q-icon name="add" size="15px"></q-icon>
</q-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **`Quasar v2.0.4`**. With **`Quasar v2.0.4`**, you can change the icon(or button) size with **`size attribute`**.

For example:

```html
<q-btn size="xl" icon="close" />

<q-btn size="100px" icon="close" />
```

But if you use **`size attribute`** with **`fab`** or **`fab-mini attribute`** , **`size attribute`** doesn't work, then, only **`fab`** or **`fab-mini attribute`** works instead of **`size attribute`**.

For example:

```html
<q-btn size="xl" fab icon="close" />
    
<q-btn size="100px" fab-mini icon="close" />
```